# How to have the base class be aware of derived class properties?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to create a base class that will be used in storing data in key/value manner. The base class will generate the keys and is responsible for storing the data. When the base class is inherited, the derived class can specify it's own key but the the base class has to be aware of the derived classes' key. For example:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   private string key = "Parent";

   public void GenerateKey()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(key);
   }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
   public string key = "Feature";

}

public class SubFeatureClass : FeatureClass 
{
   public string key = "SubFeature";

}

FeatureClass feature = new FeatureClass();
feature.GenerateKey(); //I would like this to produce "Parent_Feature"

SubFeatureClass subFeature = new SubFeatureClass();
subFeatureClass.GenerateKey(); //I would like this to generate "Parent_Feature_SubFeature"
```

How can I make the base class be aware of its children's keys regardless of how many levels of inheritance has occurred.

Comment: is this worded correctly? You want the inherited classes to be aware of how many levels from the base class there is? Your question sounds confusing as if you were trying to find out how many times the base class has been derived - if it's not me misunderstanding then can you please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by making the base method `virtual` and referencing it in the override:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   public virtual string key {get {return "Parent";}}

   public void GenerateKey()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(key);
   }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
   public override string key {get{return base.key +  "_Feature";}}

}

public class SubFeatureClass : FeatureClass 
{
   public override string key {get{return base.key +  "_SubFeature";}}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract or virtual functions can be used to achieve this (which one depends on whether it makes sense for `ParentClass` to be the actual type or whether it always needs a derived class.

In any case, you would have a virtual (or abstract) function which you override in the derived class to return the special key. In fact, in C# you can have virtual/abstract properties:

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
   private string key = "Parent";

   protected abstract string derivedKey
   {
        get;
   }

   public void GenerateKey()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(key + derivedKey);
   }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
   public override string derivedKey
   {
        get
        {
             return "Feature";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're shadowing the property, not overriding it, so this won't work.

Comment: Ooops, knew I should have tried it with a compiler, will fix

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, using `virtual` properties,

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public virtual string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return "Parent";
        }
    }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
    public override string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Key + "_" + "Feature";
        }
    }

}

public class SubFeatureClass : FeatureClass 
{
    public override string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Key + "_" + "SubFeature";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could use it this way,

```
FeatureClass feature = new FeatureClass();
Console.WriteLine(feature.Key); // <-- "Parent_Feature"

SubFeatureClass subFeature = new SubFeatureClass();
Console.WriteLine(subFeature.Key); // <-- "Parent_Feature_SubFeature"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual property instead of a field:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   public ParentClass(){Key = "Parent";}
   private virtual string Key {get;set;}

   public void GenerateKey()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(Key);
   }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
    public FeatureClass(){Key = base.Key + "_" + "Feature";}
    override string Key {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParentClass
{
    protected List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    public ParentClass()
    {
        keys.Add("Parent");
    }

    public void GenerateKey()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("_", keys));
    }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
    public FeatureClass()
    {
        keys.Add("Feature");
    }
}

public class SubFeatureClass : FeatureClass
{
    public SubFeatureClass()
    {
        keys.Add("SubFeature");
    }

}
```

Comment: The derived types won't have access to `keys` here.

Comment: sorry! It shoud be Public :)

Comment: It should be `protected`.  Being public means it could be messed with by other types, which it should not be.

Comment: Also, you have `keys.Add` just floating in the class's definition.  That won't compile.  They need to be in a constructor.

Comment: Yeah I tried to write on Notepad. I am going to edit

Answer (score 0):

Using constructor overloading and constructor chaining in my version:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private string key;

    protected ParentClass(string childKeys)
    {
        key = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(childKeys) ? key + "Parent_" + childKeys : key;
    }

    public void GenerateKey()
    {
        // Get keys from subclasses
        Console.WriteLine(key);

    }
}

public class FeatureClass : ParentClass
{
    public FeatureClass() : base("Feature") { }
    protected FeatureClass(string key) : base("Feature_" + key) { }
}

public class SubFeatureClass : FeatureClass 
{
    public SubFeatureClass() : base("SubFeature") { }
    protected SubFeatureClass(string key) : base("SubFeature_" + key) { }
}

public class ReallySubFeatureClass : SubFeatureClass
{
    public ReallySubFeatureClass() : base("ReallySubFeature") { }
}
```

**Test code looks just like yours but I added one more level for example:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FeatureClass feature = new FeatureClass();
        feature.GenerateKey(); //I would like this to produce "Parent_Feature"

        SubFeatureClass subFeature = new SubFeatureClass();
        subFeature.GenerateKey(); //I would like this to generate "Parent_Feature_SubFeature"

        ReallySubFeatureClass reallySubFeature = new ReallySubFeatureClass();
        reallySubFeature.GenerateKey();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]